# Advance time for Sidekiq dyno on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

For testing purposes, I'd like to advance Sidekiq clock on an Heroku dyno so Time.now returns a date in the future.

I already do that in Rspec with `travel_to` but I'd like the full dyno process to have another time.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look into the `timecop` gem.